# Transaction state is SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased when restore

Tags: objective-c, in-app-purchase

Every time launch the app, I call the restore method:

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
```

I check the transaction state changes in the event:

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {
        switch (transaction.transactionState) {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                NSLog (@"SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased");
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                NSLog (@"SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed");
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                NSLog (@"SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored");
                break;              
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, the log always display "SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored" though I haven't any new purchase. Is this problem occur in sandbox only or how to fix it?

Comment: your title and your comment are not coherent. Are you saying in your comment that "The problem is, the log always display **"SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased"** though I haven't any new purchase. Is this problem occur in sandbox only or how to fix it?"